# c# IE Plugin BHO get the pdf

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, pdf, bho

I need help for a little IE Plugin (Browser Helper Object).

**What the Plugin should do:**

If the user clicks on a link with pdf behind, the plugin should call an exe file installed on the computer. The exe file would check the PDF and open the default pdf application or a special one.

**What i have done:**

My BHO starts with my IE. I used this code for the beginning:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19971/How-to-attach-to-Browser-Helper-Object-BHO-with-C

 I disabled all adobe plugins so the ie download window shows up. Whit this code i can parse the html body add html markup etc. but thats not what i'm trying to do...

**My Problem:**

I don't know how to grab the pdf. If i call directly a pdf download link the cast of the site object into a InternetExplorer or WebBrowser Object fails.

```
public int SetSite(object site)
{
    if (site != null)
    {
        ieInstance = site as InternetExplorer;   
        ieInstance.DocumentComplete += new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
    }
    else if (ieInstance != null)
    {
        ieInstance.DocumentComplete -= new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Document = '((SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)(ieInstance)).Document' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

**Could someone tell me, how i can grab the pdf befor the download window in the IE appears? I know there is a Event before download, but also this event don't help me.**

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve more broadly?

You can't grab a HTML document instance when the browser is showing a PDF file because there isn't one-- the PDF object is loaded instead of the HTML-rendering object.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, there are likely better ways to accomplish it (most likely by [registering a MIME Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the application/pdf MIME type).

Comment: The plugin should grab the pdf and start an application. Like the adobe pdf plugin. The only thing i need is to identify if the http response is a pdf. Than grab the pdf and send it to the application or save it local without user interaction.

Comment: Maybe i used the wrong words. Could you explain me how to registering a MIME Filter or post link? I thought the InternetExplorer or WebBrowser object also contains the pdf...

Comment: The "WebBrowser" object is really a "Shell document viewer" which can host many different types of objects. Typically, it hosts a Trident object (MSHTML.dll's implementation of a HTML document object) but it can also host other types of objects like Microsoft Office viewers, and, in this case, Adobe's PDF Viewer. When it is hosting one of those other objects, the document object isn't Trident/MSHTML and thus it won't support the interfaces you're looking for.